# To show correctly PRIMARY KEY in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, primary-key

**Which one of the following ways would you use in declaring Primary Keys by Postgres?**

### #1

```
CREATE TABLE user(
    user_id PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
)
```

### #2

```
CREATE TABLE user(
    user_id NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT user_pk PRIMARY KEY(user_id);
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use method #1.

- The indication of which column is the primary key is kept closer to the actual column definition
- You don't have to think up a name for the constraint; a name will be automatically generated

One reason to use method #2 is if your primary key were to span more than one column. In that case, method #1 won't work because it only supports a single column primary key.

Comment: I agree with you! - Thank you for your answer!